# In D3,How do I rotate a letter after laying out its location using transform rotate?

Tags: css, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to rotate labels after laying out them for Chord diagram in D3.
However, after laying out the letter the anchor point of the letter is same as before,
which eventually rotating the character in a way that I didn't intended.

How do I rotate the lettters keeping its position?

I laid out label and my chord diagram using the following code.

```
d3.selectAll('.arcs').each(function(d, i) {
    let mydata = d3.select(this).data();
    svg.selectAll('labels').data(nameArray)
        .join('text')
        .text((d, i) => { return d })
        .attr('class', 'textlabel')
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('transform',
            function(t, k) {
                return ` rotate(${midPoint(figureCalculation,k)}) translate(${outterRadius},0)`
            })
})






function groupTicks(t) {
    let d = t[0]

    let k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 10

    return d3.range(0, 11).map(function(v, i) {
        return {
            angle: v * k + d.startAngle,
        }

    })
};

function midPoint(array, index) {

    let targetArray = array;
    let start = array.groups[index].startAngle;
    let end = array.groups[index].endAngle;
    let midAngle = (start + end) / 2;
    let midDegree = (midAngle * 180 / Math.PI) - 90

    return midDegree;
}
```

And the letters I want to rotate keepin its relative position are as below.

[image]

The complete code in the following link.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/QWKMYyM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `text` in a `g` and transform the `g` then rotate the `text` opposite of the `g`.

```js
let margin = {
  top: 50,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 20,
  right: 20
}

let width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
let height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * 0.4;
let outterRadius = innerRadius * 1.2
let svg = d3.select('#graph').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2 + margin.left}, ${height / 2 + margin.top})`)

var colorArray = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange']
var nameArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
var matrix = [
  [11975, 5871, 8916, 2868],
  [1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [1013, 990, 940, 6907]
];

var matrix1 = [
  [175, 571, 916, 868],
  [1951, 1248, 2060, 5471],
  [8010, 14145, 4390, 4245],
  [1213, 990, 540, 1207]
];

var fillColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(nameArray)
  .range(colorArray)


let figureCalculation = d3.chord()
  .padAngle(0.05)
  .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)(matrix)


console.log(figureCalculation);
figureCalculation.chords = [];
figureCalculation.forEach((d) => {
  figureCalculation.chords.push(d)
})


console.log(midPoint(figureCalculation, 0))


var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outterRadius)



var arcs = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'arcs')
  .selectAll('arcs').data(figureCalculation.groups)
  .join('path')
  .attr('class', (d, i) => {
    return `arc ${nameArray[i]}`
  })
  .attr('d', arc)
  .style('fill', (d, i) => {
    return fillColor(nameArray[i])
  })
  .style('opacity', 0.7)

var chords = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'chords').selectAll('chords')
  .data(figureCalculation.chords)
  .join('path')
  .attr('d', d3.ribbon().radius(innerRadius))
  .style('stroke', 'grey')
  .style('stroke-width', 0.5)
  .style('fill', (d, i) => {
    if (d.target.index == 0) {
      return colorArray[0]
    } else if (d.target.index == 1) {
      return colorArray[1]
    } else if (d.target.index == 2) {
      return colorArray[2]
    } else {
      return colorArray[3]
    }
  })
  .style('opacity', 0.5)


arcs.each(function(d, i) {
  let mydata = d3.select(this).data()
  svg.append('g').attr('class', 'ticks').selectAll('ticks')
    .data(groupTicks(mydata))
    .join('line')
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 7)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return `rotate(${d.angle*(180/Math.PI)-90})
            translate(${outterRadius},0)
            `
    })

    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style('stroke-width', 0.3)
})

d3.selectAll('.arcs').each(function(d, i) {
  let mydata = d3.select(this).data();

  svg.selectAll('labels').data(nameArray)
    .join('g')
    .attr('transform',
      function(t, k) {
        return ` rotate(${midPoint(figureCalculation,k)}) translate(${outterRadius},0)`
      })
    .append('text')
    .text((d, i) => {
      return d
    })
    .attr('class', 'textlabel')
    .attr('transform',
      function(t, k) {
        var r = -midPoint(figureCalculation,k);
        var a = Math.abs(r) > 90 ? -15 : 15; // fudge factor
        return `rotate(${r})translate(${a},0)`
      });
})






function groupTicks(t) {
  let d = t[0]

  let k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 10

  return d3.range(0, 11).map(function(v, i) {
    return {
      angle: v * k + d.startAngle,
    }

  })
};

function midPoint(array, index) {

  let targetArray = array;
  let start = array.groups[index].startAngle;
  let end = array.groups[index].endAngle;
  let midAngle = (start + end) / 2;
  let midDegree = (midAngle * 180 / Math.PI) - 90

  return midDegree;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```